# Can you identify this spaceship?

Tags: spaceship, object-identification

This is a picture from "Top Secret", a games magazine from Poland published in 1989.

Some of the pictures in the magazine they drew themselves. But many others were just cropped pictures from movie/game posters. I believe this is also a cropped/modified poster. They used it as a background pic for an "Aliens: The Computer Game" (1987) game but I don't think this is a ship from Aliens. I googled Aliens' posters and no match.

[image]

There is some rectangular blocking in the picture because I removed game-related info.1

Original pic (a bit retouched scan):

[image: Original image]

Here is a cropped image of just the spaceship:

[image: cropped]

Comment: I wonder if it’s concept art that never became a movie prop

Comment: @ToddWilcox I don't think they had access to anything "exclusive"

Comment: That specific mis-drawing of the spaceship's underside is ringing alarm bells, but I can't dredge up the specific memory.

Comment: Maybe it's supposed to be the salvage ship from the start of the movie, or some version of Gateway station.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a closeup of just  the spaceship. Feel free to revert the edit if you don't want that.  I can swear this was in _Omni_ or on a book cover.