# Can you identify this green fish-like humanoid warrior with a stick (spear?)?

Tags: character-identification

I am trying to identify this fantasy creature. It was used in an article about "D'N'D" in a polish magazine "Top Secret" #14 (February 1993)

[image]

After hours of googling I found a few similar images:

a Commodore-64 demoscene image by Cruise:

[image]

Lovecraft bestiary:

[image]

and something called Bullywug:

[image]

But can't find the magazine image. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It looks like you found the Bullywug. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Bullywug has different feet

Comment: [This "Top Secret"](https://m.pouet.net/prod.php?which=20491)?

Comment: Reminds me of some amphibious creatures from Andre Norton's post-apocalypse novel "No Night Without Stars"

Comment: @FuzzyBoots This: https://archive.org/details/TopSecret14/page/n3/mode/2up

Comment: You might have found two different versions of the same creature. Both bullywugs, just two different ideas for the feet. It’s possible that it’s an unlicensed copy of the bullywug art with some minor changes to avoid copyright infringement. Do you have any other parts of the *Top Secret* magazine? Or just this image?

Comment: @ToddWilcox I have the whole magazine but there is nothing more about this create in that magazine. The bullywug image I posted is quite recent, the magazine is very old. So magazine's version would seem like the original. But all other images of bullywugs on the internet have frog-like feet. Hence I believe it could be something else, not a bullywug.

Comment: There are many creatures from D&D and other games that have changed over the years.

Comment: @Giter Yes. This creature is just a "generic fantasy image" for the article.

Comment: The C64 demoscene image definitely seems to be the same image - note the cloven hooves. The creator, Cruise, is Polish - just as the magazine is. So it's highly likely the source is Polish. (Or else one of the magazine or Cruise copied the other).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found it! This monster is from a 1982 artwork by [Boris Vallejo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Vallejo) called "The Witch and her Familiar".

[image]

The monster, then, is meant to be the familiar of a witch. The artwork was used as the cover art for the [December 1982 edition of Marvel's Epic Illustrated magazine](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Epic_Illustrated_Vol_1_15).

After tracking down the Commodore 64 demo mentioned in the OP, I started by trying to find any of the images in the slideshow. Eventually a google image search for "Barbarian fantasy cover art poland" had one of the images in the demo as the first result, which showed me that the image was from an art by Boris Vallejo. After searching through artwork by Boris Vallejo, I quickly realised that all of the images in the demo were by him, so then it was a case of trawling through every repository of Boris' art I could find online until I stumbled across the image with the creature in question - eventually tracked it down on [a website where all the thumbnails were broken](https://tronche.com/graphical-art/boris-vallejo/82/), so I had to go into each larger image one by one to check them!

Comment: Speaking of Top Secret magazine, don't forget that we've still got these to find https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/245646/can-you-identify-this-spaceship + https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/246244/can-you-identify-this-indiana-jones-like-hero

Comment: That is some amazing detective work! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Valorum I keep them in the back of my head, every once in a while try finding again, but still didn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 2):

(Advanced) Dungeons & Dragons has had a variety of [piscine humanoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_piscine_and_amphibian_humanoids) since 1st edition at least. You can see the menagerie below, and take your pick, but I think your first green image looks most like a Locathah (especially the 1st edition AD&D spear wielders) or Kuo-Toa (1st edition AD&D likewise wielding spears):

Could be a Locathah

[image: 1e Monster Manual Locathah]
[image: 5e Ghosts of Saltmarsh Locathah]

Could be be a Nixie

[image: 1e Monster Manual Nixie]

Could be a Sahaugin

[image: 1e Monster Manual Sahaugin]

Could be a Kuo-Toa

[image: 1e Fiend Folio Kuo-Toa]
[image: 1e D1-D2 Kuo-Toa]
[image: 5e Monster Manual Kuo-Toa]

It is **probably not** a Merman, Morkoth, or Triton since the image you share has legs, and not fish tails (split or not) or tentacles:

[image: 1e Monster Manual Merman]
[image: 1e Monster Manual Morkoth]
[image: 1e Monster Manual Triton]

Also, Dungeons & Dragons has had a few amphibious humanoids, notably the Bullywugs, Gripili, Grung, and, arguably, Salamanders (although the latter are fire creatures):

[image: 1e I6 Bullywug]
[image: 1e Monster Manual II Gripili]
[image: 5e One Grung Above Grung]
[image: 1e Monster Manual Salamander]

Comment: Very informative, thank you, but someone found the exact image so I gotta accept the other answer.

Comment: @Tom Oh! You were not asking "what is this creature," but "what is this artwork". Got it. :)